# AzDO application registration appRoles disable issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In azure application registrations you can see all the approles in the manifest.

I need to change these roles in the pipeline every time we deploy infrastructure.

How do i disable them all quickly?  Is there a quick way?

I am currently, looping all the approles and setting the enabled property to false before i upload the whole manifest again. (There may be new roles in the manifest hence the destroy and reload approach)

Answer (score 0):

Is ok, I have found the problem.
When updating using `az ad app update --approles @manifest`, the manifest file must include the id's of the existing approles else you cant set the isenabled property to false.

I am now playing with the MS graph to see how I can orchestrate this.  Thanks!